# Google calendar integration for a Slack chatbot ChatOps/Lita

Tags: ruby, slack, chatbot, lita

I'm trying to see if there's a Google Calendar integration for a [Slack](https://slack.com/) chatbot? I'm using [Lita](https://github.com/litaio/lita), ChatOps for Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google Calendar plugin in the [lita.io plugin page](https://plugins.lita.io/) so far.

But searching on GitHub I found a plugin project which might help you get started using the Google Calendar Api on your bot.

The link for the repo is https://github.com/platanus/lita-google-birthdates